# how to run def function in conditonal statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, while-loop

```
A = int(input("masukan angka A: "))
B = int(input("masukan angka B: "))
C = int(input("masukan angka A: "))
print(f"anda memasukan angka A:{A}, B:{B}, C:{C}")
def putarbilangan(A,B,C):
    A = B
    B = C
    C = A
    return putarbilangan

while True:
    tanya = input("apakah ingin diputar (yes/no) ?")
    if tanya == "yes":
        print("ok")
        putarbilangan()
        break
    elif tanya == "no":
        print("program selesai")
        break
    else:
        print("anda salah memilih")
        break
```

hello , i want to make a program about change number A = 2, B =1, C=3 change to be A = 3, B = 2, C =1
but  i get stuck
can you help me ?
i can't understand to make function in statement

Comment: your function is returning itself, i.e. returning function object. In addition inside the function you manipulate the arguments, i.e. that are local scope names, that "live" only inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = int(input("masukan angka A: "))
B = int(input("masukan angka B: "))
C = int(input("masukan angka C: "))
print(f"anda memasukan angka A:{A}, B:{B}, C:{C}")


def putarbilangan():
    global A
    global B
    global C
    A, B, C = B, C, A


while True:
    tanya = input("apakah ingin diputar (yes/no) ?")
    if tanya == "yes":
        print("ok")
        putarbilangan()
        print(f"anda memasukan angka A:{A}, B:{B}, C:{C}")
        break
    elif tanya == "no":
        print("program selesai")
        break
    else:
        print("anda salah memilih")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to enter **putarbilangan(A,B,C)** in line 15

```
A = int(input("masukan angka A: "))
B = int(input("masukan angka B: "))
C = int(input("masukan angka A: "))
print(f"anda memasukan angka A:{A}, B:{B}, C:{C}")
def putarbilangan(A,B,C):
    A = B
    B = C
    C = A
    return putarbilangan

while True:
    tanya = input("apakah ingin diputar (yes/no) ?")
    if tanya == "yes":
        print("ok")
        putarbilangan(A,B,C)
        break
    elif tanya == "no":
        print("program selesai")
        break
    else:
        print("anda salah memilih")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the local scope problem pointed out be buran in the comment, the assignment does not work as you expected. Assume the input is A = 2, B =1, C=3

```
A = B  # makes A = 1, B =1, C=3
B = C  # makes A = 2, B =3, C=3
C = A  # makes A = 2, B =1, C=2
```

So the value of 3 is lost. You can call the function and use the return value to assign changes.

```
def putarbilangan(A,B,C):
    return C, A, B

A, B, C = putarbilangan(A,B,C)
```

or just

```
A, B, C = C, A, B
```